# What is wrong with my Stack/isPalindrome() class/method?

Tags: java

For this method I needed to implement a custom made `Stack` class to see if the given string is a palindrome.

This is the custom `Stack` class:

```
public class Stack<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private T head;

    public Stack() {
        arrayList.add(head);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return arrayList.toString();
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return arrayList.size() == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    public T push(T element) {
        arrayList.add(element);
        head = element;
        return element;
    }

    public T pop() {
        T returnVal = arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1);
        if (!empty()) {
            arrayList.remove(returnVal);
            head = arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    public T peek() {
        return head;
    }
}
```

And this is the palindrome method:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String string) {
        var stack = new Stack<Character>();
        var flag = true;
        for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++)
            stack.push(string.charAt(i));
        if (string.charAt(0) == stack.peek()) {
            for (int j=0; j<string.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println(string.charAt(j) + " " + stack.peek());
                if (string.charAt(j) != stack.pop()) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
        return flag;
    }
```

When I run the method, it runs the loop only 2 times. The `Stack` object doesn't seem to pop. But when I tested the `pop()` method in the main method with just a set of different characters, it seemed to work. But in this `isPalindrome()` method, it doesn't seem to me that it works. Can someone please help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Stack.pop()` method, the line `arrayList.remove(returnVal);` is not what you want.

It will remove the first occurrence of `returnVal` from the stack, but in `pop()` you need to remove the last occurrence of `returnVal`.

In `Stack.pop()` you need to remove the last element - which means you need to write

```
arrayList.remove(arrayList.size()-1);
```

Your complete `Stack.pop()` method would then be:

```
public T pop() {
    T returnVal = arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1);
    if (!empty()) {
        arrayList.remove(arrayList.size()-1);
        head = arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```